# Reading from a text file using C#

Tags: c#

So I'm making a chat program but I am having issues creating a new line in the text box instead of overwriting the other message. Here is my code:

```
        private void refreshRate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        String ChatPath = @"Path";
        String line;
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Path");
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            richTextBox1.Text = null;
            while (line != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                richTextBox1.Text = line;
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + r.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: when I run the program, it shows the chat just fine. only the bottom line of it. When the text file gets updated, the one I just saw goes away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `StreamReader` or `Environment.NewLine`

```
richTextBox1.Text=File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, I didn't know that you didn't need all that stuff!

Answer (score 1):

If you change
  `richTextBox1.Text = line` to      `richTextBox1.AppendText(line);` you'll lose the last line so change the `while` block as:

```
while (line != null)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);        
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    richTextBox1.AppendText(line??"");
}
```

Comment: ok that sort of works, but now it never stops writing the text file, I get infinite copies of it

Comment: it writes the file? @8bitMonkeyLogik

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the line

```
richTextBox1.Text = line;
```

and add

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(line);
```

after you've read it from the file.